# VS Code Update Service Permission Denied Error

Tags: visual-studio-code

All of the sudden, I'm getting this error every time I start VS Code on OSX. I tried to give read & write permissions to everyone for the .vscode folder, but I still get the error. Any ideas on how to resolve it?

VS Code version 1.32.1

OSX version 10.14.3

[image]

Comment: Seems like you need to fix the permissions in the `~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt` logs. Simply execute this: `sudo chown $USER ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt`.